# Converting from excel formula for Using forecast with times

Tags: vba, excel

When using forecast, you input a number and it should return a value based on the known X data and Known Y data.
However if you put in a time this does not work.

I need two things.
First of all I need the VBA equivalent of forecast. I suspect this to be `application.forecast` 
Then how to use the date as a value for the forecast to work as it should
The formula is as follows:
`=FORECAST(15:00:00,A10:A33,B10:B33)`
Currently this equation flags up an error.

Any ideas to get this to work for time values?

Comment: [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le)

Comment: Roger, I'll delete it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two potential problem areas. The first is the time. Use the [TIME function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIME-function-9A5AFF99-8F7D-4611-845E-747D0B8D5457) to get a precise time. Second, in D9:D12, the values are left-aligned. Typically, this means they are text, not true numbers. If you absolutely require the *m* suffix, use a Custom number Format of `General\m` in order that they retain their numeric status while displaying an *m* as an increment suffix. If you type the *m* in, they become text-that-look-like-numbers and are useless for any maths.

```
=FORECAST(TIME(15, 0, 0), B10:B33, A10:A33)
```

That returns 3.401666667 which is either 09:38 AM or 3.4 m (it's been a while since I played with the [FORECAST function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FORECAST-function-50CA49C9-7B40-4892-94E4-7AD38BBEDA99)).

Comment: Awesome, answered just like that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ah no the forecast isn't working at all. See the trend works fine on the graph and changes via the values. It just. doesn't find x from y value

Comment: You may have your x's and y's mixed up. See [FORECAST function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FORECAST-function-50CA49C9-7B40-4892-94E4-7AD38BBEDA99). I used make the same mistake all the time.